# How to redeem an American Airlines voucher?

Tags: american-airlines, vouchers

Recently I traveled with American Airlines. I had a bad experience as I felt they were terribly outdated, so I complained with their customer service, who, ironically, gave me a paper voucher that I can redeem on my next flight.

Now... seems like this paper voucher that looks like a plane ticket can't be used while booking online, is that true? 
How I can redeem it? I read somewhere that I have to do a phone reservation and then mail the voucher. Really? That's so outdated

Comment: Every time I've received a voucher, there are redemption instructions printed right on it.  Is that not the case with yours?

Comment: No, they just sent me this voucher in an envelope

Comment: It just says "Here is the transportation voucher you were promised. This voucher may be used toward the purchase of a ticket on American for yourself, or anyone you choose" - no extra instructions, no website link

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need to involve an agent to redeem it. Whether you'll have to mail it I'm not sure (it probably has a unique number on it?), but at the very least I'm pretty confident you'll need to call them.

Comment: Anyone know if you can mail in these vouchers Registered Mail? I called AA and not even they know.

Comment: I've redeemed an AA voucher. I was travelling so coulld use it by booking at the airport which was far easier than any ohter method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I contacted them and I got this response:

When booking, select "place booking on hold" (screenshot:)
[image: screenshot]
Then, call them and give the paper voucher code and the booking number that you will see in the next page. They will adjust the price for you to pay.

After that, **mail the voucher to their address**, (like e-mail was never invented... VERY ironic compensation to give to someone that complained saying that their systems are outdated).

Comment: Yep, AA still has mostly paper vouchers, unfortunately. While they have been updating much of their technology, this part is still pretty outdated.

Comment: If you don't want to pay certified mail, If you have a copy, you can bring it in on the day of travel after the agent confirms the hold on the trip(record locator).

Comment: 25 July 2018 I just went  through this exact process - making a reservation,  putting it on hold, then calling.   It worked as described.  But not I have to rush to the post office to get it stamped before midnight or else the fares will recalculate!

Answer (score 3):

I just called yesterday May 20 2016, to clarify how to use a paper voucher issued to another family member I had an internet reservation I had made for a flight on hold at the time and was trying to understand how to use the voucher to purchase the ticket on line. I was told paper vouchers can NOT be used for payment on line and that you have to call in but they waive any ticketing fee. Then, I was told I could not use it as the voucher was not in my name. I voiced upset at this as we were told the voucher could be "transferred" or used by someone else, plus it was given to render payment for errors that American had made on the last flight. The rep spoke to someone and got it approved for use. The rep then directed I had to mail it in by a certain date or deliver it in person at an airport terminal of AA. I asked what happens if it gets lost in the system or not received for some reason, she advised to take a photo picture and copy. Mailing it is more complicated as you have to note certain things outside and inside the envelope, but if mailed, rep gave address of Dept 109 5031 Commerce Park Circle Pensacola, Fl. 32505. Hope this helps all others who get these paper vouchers. If I knew what I know now, would have asked for an e-voucher.

Comment: I can confirm I had the same experience, with the same address.

Answer (score 2):

If it has a 19-digit card number and a 4-digit pin number on it, it may be an "eVoucher".  You can check it at https://evouchers.aa.com.

If so, you can buy your ticket online at http://aa.com.  One of the payment options is "Gift card / eVoucher".

If not, call AA and ask for guidance.

Comment: No, it has 13 digits and no pin number, it's a classic, 1980-style voucher. Very ironic to give as a compensation to someone that complained about the obsolescense of the airline :D

Answer (score 2):

I just called as well.  Here is what AA said:

- Transportation Vouchers can only be used on flights booked at least 12 days in advance.
- The website won't give you the option to place a booking on hold if you are making a reservation less than 12 days.
- They can book it over the phone without charging the 25$ reservation fee.
- Good for one year.
- Staff on the phone don't really know the conditions: one told me it was only good for domestic travel US only; another said it was good for any AA flight.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable.  They are stone-aged.

Have to call.  it then takes 12 days.

Yes.  Must mail the voucher back to AA.  You also have to write the flight, date, booking code o the envelope, or they wont credit the voucher.